# Подключение keycloak-esia-jcp-provider

Tags: maven, есиа, keycloak

При настройке провайдера `keycloak` для ЕСИА столкнулась со следующей ошибкой:

> 08:04:59,493 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.resources.IdentityBrokerService] (default
> task-2) identityProviderUnexpectedErrorMessage:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toLowerCase()"
> because the return value of
> "org.keycloak.models.FederatedIdentityModel.getUserName()" is null

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите, пожалуйста, как её исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Наталья, добрый день.

Мы пока не распространяем этот провайдер как open source решение, его можно, конечно, физически скачать с нашего мавен репозитория, но это не значит что вы можете свободно его использовать. Если нужна консультация - напишите нам на корпоративную почту.